# Algebra of operators abstractly isomorphic to a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $\mathcal{B}(H)$ be the algebra of bounded operators on $H$, and let $A\subseteq\mathcal{B}(H)$ be a closed subalgebra (but not necessarily a $*$-algebra).  Let $B$ be an $C^*$-algebra and let $\theta:A\rightarrow B$ be a (bounded) algebra isomorphism (again, we ignore the involution).  Can we say anything about how $A$ and $H$ relate?

For example, I could start with $B\subseteq \mathcal{B}(H)$ being a closed $*$-subalgebra.  Let $T\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ be invertible, and let $A = \{ TxT^{-1} : x\in B \}$.  If $T$ is not unitary, then in general $A$ will not be a $*$-algebra, but it is isomorphic to $B$.

- Do all examples arise from some variation of this construction?
- If I require that $\theta$ be an isometry, can we say more?

Comment: When $A$ is a C$^*$-algebra, what you are asking is the similarity problem, which is still open if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes, of course!  Thank you.  A survey, if anyone is interested, is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005077

Comment: Nice. There's also [Ozawa's](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~narutaka/notes/similarity.pdf) from 2006.